# How can I convert this to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I convert the following to [this kind of MySQL query](http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2012/06/sql-server-using-ctecommon-table.html)? I tried it to run in MySQL editor, but it looks like the syntax is different in MySQL.

```
-- Working Example
;WITH CTECompany
AS
(
    SELECT 
        EmpID, 
        ParentID, 
        PersonName , 
        0 AS HLevel,
        CAST(RIGHT(REPLICATE('_',5) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),EmpID),20) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderByField
    FROM @Company
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        C.EmpID, 
        C.ParentID, 
        C.PersonName , 
        (CTE.HLevel + 1) AS HLevel,
        CTE.OrderByField + CAST(RIGHT(REPLICATE('_',5) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),C.EmpID),20) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderByField
    FROM @Company C
    INNER JOIN CTECompany CTE ON CTE.EmpID = C.ParentID
    WHERE C.ParentID IS NOT NULL
)

-- Working Example
SELECT 
    EmpID
    , ParentID
    , HLevel
    , PersonName
    , (REPLICATE( '----' , HLevel ) + PersonName) AS Person
FROM CTECompany
ORDER BY OrderByField,PersonName;
```

Comment: That is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Well... what is there to say. You rewrite SQL Server specific functions with MySQL ones (where possible), and change the syntax. **What is the question here?**

Comment: Please highlight what specific issues you're experiencing. SO is not a code writing/translating service. It's specifically intended to help developers solve specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have `WITH`. Just move that query into a subquery, replacing `CTECompany` in the second part of the query

```
SELECT 
    EmpID
    , ParentID
    , HLevel
    , PersonName
    , (REPLICATE( '----' , HLevel ) + PersonName) AS Person
FROM (
        SELECT 
            EmpID, 
            ParentID, 
            PersonName , 
            0 AS HLevel,
            CAST(RIGHT(REPLICATE('_',5) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),EmpID),20) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderByField
        FROM Company
        WHERE ParentID IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            C.EmpID, 
            C.ParentID, 
            C.PersonName , 
            (CTE.HLevel + 1) AS HLevel,
            CTE.OrderByField + CAST(RIGHT(REPLICATE('_',5) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),C.EmpID),20) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderByField
        FROM Company C
        INNER JOIN CTECompany CTE ON CTE.EmpID = C.ParentID
        WHERE C.ParentID IS NOT NULL
    )
ORDER BY OrderByField,PersonName;
```

MySQL also doesn't allow variables to be used as table names, so I changed `@Company` to `Company`.